How to connect unity dots client and server using unity Relay
I'm trying to make my DOTS game playalbe via Unity Relay. The issue is my client doesn't connect to the server even though I pass port and ip to it.
Thats my connection manger code
public void StartRelayHost(int port, string conIP)
{

    DestoryLocalSimulationWorld();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    
    var serverWorld = ClientServerBootstrap.CreateServerWorld("server");
    ushort Port = (ushort )port;
    var listenReq = ServerWorld.EntityManager.CreateEntity(typeof(NetworkStreamRequestListen));
    ServerWorld.EntityManager.SetComponentData(listenReq,new NetworkStreamRequestListen {Endpoint = ClientServerBootstrap.DefaultListenAddress.WithPort(Port)});
    StartRelayClient(port, conIP);
}

private void StartRelayClient(int port, string conIP)
{
    Debug.Log("server" + port + " " + conIP);
    DestoryLocalSimulationWorld();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    Debug.Log("client " + port + " " + conIP);
    var clientWorld = ClientServerBootstrap.CreateClientWorld("client");
    ushort  Port = (ushort )port;
    var connectionEndpoint = NetworkEndpoint.Parse(conIP, Port);
    {
        using var query =
            clientWorld.EntityManager.CreateEntityQuery(ComponentType.ReadWrite<NetworkStreamDriver>());
        query.GetSingletonRW<NetworkStreamDriver>().ValueRW.Connect(clientWorld.EntityManager,connectionEndpoint);
    }
    World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld = clientWorld;
}

And thats how i pass Relay data
public async void CreateRelay()
{
    try
    {
       Allocation allocation = await RelayService.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(3);
       joincode = await RelayService.Instance.GetJoinCodeAsync(allocation.AllocationId);
       _connectionManager.StartRelayHost(allocation.RelayServer.Port ,allocation.RelayServer.IpV4);
    }
    catch(RelayServiceException e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e);
    }
}

With this set-up my client is always on connecting even though server and subscene seem to load correctly
